# Get Value from Win32_Environment WMI Query

Tags: powershell

How can I get `VariableValue3` and put it to `$myVariable` as a string?

```
get-wmiobject -class Win32_Environment | select-object Name, VariableValue

Name                     VariableValue
----                     -------------
ValueName1               VariableValue1
ValueName2               VariableValue2
ValueName3               VariableValue3
ValueName4               VariableValue4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myVariable = (Get-Wmiobject -class Win32_Environment | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ValueName3"}).VariableValue
```

Comment: But I do not know the "VariableValue3", I just want to GET this value based on "ValueName3". In addition your query does not work.

Comment: @Sharpowski Apologies, typo, corrected now. You specify the `Name` value (`ValueName3`) and will get back the VariableValue (`VariableValue3`)